# Getting grey screen in release mode when using gridview.builder flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting a grey screen when using gridview.builder. In debug mode, I am not getting any errors. But grey screen comes in release apk. please help if you have any solution. I am stuck with this from a couple of days. Thanks in advance

Comment: Gray screens on release modes are the equivelent of red ones on debug. Something is crashing there.

Comment: can you please show the code

Answer (score 0):

Your GridView has a `RenderFlex` error. Try wrapping it into a `SizedBox`.

```dart
SizedBox(
 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
 child: GridView(),
),
```